# Trigger a function again after getting value from local storage

Tags: html

I'm working on storing the selected option into localStorage. The problem is that I can't refresh the currency function again after getting the value from localStorage. As you can see from the fiddle, once you have selected an option and reloaded the page, the option is set to the previously selected one, but the price isn't able to change because of failure to trigger the function again. I've tried this code but it won't work:

```
$(document).on("change","#convert", function() {
    option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
    localStorage.setItem('money', option);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trigger the change of the select after you set its value.

```
$("#convert").val(localStorage.getItem('money'));
//add this line below
$('#convert').trigger('change');
```

Here is a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QE9V3/